# How to determine the right size of gnuplot terminal output?

Tags: visualization-software, publishing, gnuplot

When using gnuplot scripts to generate graphs in PDF format, there is the `size` option. I would like to know how one can estimate the right size of the output graph to place in a scientific paper.

Comment: Documentation for [pdfcairo](http://gensoft.pasteur.fr/docs/gnuplot/5.0.4/node479.html), for [pdf](http://gensoft.pasteur.fr/docs/gnuplot/5.0.4/node478.html).

Comment: Meta discussion relevant to this question: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/291/671

Comment: Normally, I output the graphs to PDF in a A4 size. The final figure size, I tailored in the LaTeX document.

Comment: Good idea @Camps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Camps has the right idea here: Make the image with gnuplot as large as you need, then scale the size down in whatever program you are using to write your paper.

Answer (score 3):

Output to a large size with a lot of whitespace (A4 is usually fine) and then trim the whitespace using `pdfcrop`, a command line tool included in every latex distribution. [See this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25807/82370) Pdfcrop is really reliable, so I do this for all my PDF graphics before I put them in my papers so tex can handle them consistently and I don't end up with weird tiny figures surrounded by whitespace.